# How to test @transactional methods

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions

I have a spring application and it needs transactions.
How would i write a test to see if the @Transactional annotation is working correctly?
I have a service class with an autowired repo, and methods like

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
 public boolean saveObjectToDb(Object a){
 repo.save(a)   

}
```

Comment: you may write your own unit test class

Comment: that was the obvious answer, i should have defined the question better i imagine... anyways my problem is that i have a method that does only one thing and i don't know how to break or interrupt it in a test to see if the transactional  annotation works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you *can* do. It isn't necessarily the best idea but here goes:

```
 @Test
 public void testTransactionality() {
   Method[] methods = YourClassWhateverItsCalled.class.getMethods();
   Optional<Method> findFirst = Arrays.stream(methods)
      .filter(method -> method.getName()
      .equals("saveObjectToDb"))
      .findFirst();

   Transactional[] annotationsByType = 
      findFirst.get().getAnnotationsByType(Transactional.class);

   assertThat(annotationsByType).isNotEmpty();
 }
```

So the specific assertion i'm using here could be more on-point for sure. However...

The reason that this isn't the best idea is because you're just testing that the annotation is there. You don't test that things are actually saved to the database. Testing things manually in a development environment has its merits and you should definitely keep in mind that you don't need to test 100% of your code. 80% is a good rule of thumb.

If you wanted to test that data is actually saved to the database that's harder. Approaches include:

- Actually having a test database that you run these kinds of tests against. Debugging these tests can be awful but they are at least fast sometimes because the database is already up and running before the test comes along.
- Spinning up an in memory database for each test of this kind and performing transactional inserts, updates, deletes against *that*. This can also be a pain because it requires a lot in terms of the test harness and the tests are slow. However if they're written well (you don't want your data from one test in a JUnit test class to end up in another without developers realising) then it can be super maintainable. Relatively speaking.

I would love to learn of more approaches here but generally speaking this is a difficult area to get right.

Update: I should note that if you test database access be sure to keep your tests *unit tests*. Nothing worse than trying to figure out what's happening with a database access test which spans 20 different classes. PURE. HELL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Test is a pretty nice way of checking for the transactional annotation. However i had to prove that my transaction will rollback if one of the DB write fails. I did a test that calls more writes and forced the interuption beetween the calls. It is a bit "hacky" and im sure that it is not the best way but it did the job!